# Error when trying to view page, following error: Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController not defined

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-6

I am getting the error below when trying to access the route, but the controller is needed to load the data:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController not defined.
```

I am using Tenancy/Multi-Tenant package and I have configured it to use routes/tenants.php to load routes specifically for tenants. If I do the following in the tenants.php file, it returns the proper response.

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return 'Test success';
});
```

though when I try to do the same, but loading the data from a controller such as this:

```
Route::get('/testt', 'TenantController@testt');
```

It will show the error:

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController not defined.
```

If i try to put the same code in web.php routes, then it works perfectly. What could be the problem? Is it something in my code? Can it be because of the multi-tenant package i'm using? How would i go about further debugging this?

Comment: I don't know but in my case sometimes, it shows error when the page was inactive for sometime, but after refreshing it works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to group the routes in `tenants.php` with the web middleware and a namespace:

```php
Route::middleware('web')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')->group(function() {
    //Routes
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Can you see if your routes are cached and try clearing that cache. Just clear project route-cache using `route:clear`

Answer (score 3):

Try `composer dump-autoload -o` 
it helped for me.

Answer (score 1):

After some minutes trying to fix I found the solution.

You don't need to group the routes if you've done in RoutesServiceProvider or in a custom Provider.

Just go to `config/tenancy.php` and go to `routes -> path`, Remove the `base_path()` function and  let the string:

```php
'path'           => base_path('routes/tenants/tenants.php'),
```

to

```php
'path'           => 'routes/tenants/tenants.php',
```

And this error should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Ignition error pages in Laravel and I have to say that I much prefer the whoops package.

I had the same error reported in this question and by chance changing the error package installed in my app to the whoops one showed me the *real* error my app was having and I was then instantly able to resolve it.   So it seemed that ignition wasn't exactly the cause but it was hindering me resolving another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error after install laravel/passport 8.1 in Laravel 6.2:

> Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined.

Fixed it runnig `composer update`. The result was:

> Updating facade/ignition (1.13.0 => 1.13.1):

Answer (score 0):

For people finding this via Google: I had a similar error with Laravel 6.5. I had messed up my AppServiceProvider with an incomplete Git merge:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
<<<<<<< HEAD
        Blade::if(
            'iscurrentroute',
            function ($route) {
                $route = Str::replaceFirst(Request::getSchemeAndHttpHost().'/', '', $route);
                return Request::is($route);
            }
        );
=======
        Blade::component('components.sortable', 'sortable');
>>>>>>> feature/WLI-58-bedrijf-beheren
    }
}
```

Deleting the "='s", "<'s", and ">'s", and the double use of Blade fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

on server side I went to /stoage folder and cleared cashs. E.g. views folder inside that /storage. Then additionally changed all entire folders' and files' permissions to can read and write.
Then pages started show up as expected