# Laravel Blade Includes within Includes

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-6.2

I currently understand the basics of Laravel Blade Components and Includes, however I'm trying to call an include from within another include.

E.g

**Input Include**

```
<!-- Alias is 'input' -->
<input type="{{ $type ?? 'text' }} value="{{ $value ?? '' }}" />
```

**Text Include**

```
<div>
    <div>Label</div>
    @input(['value'=>'Foo'])
</div>
```

**Hidden Include**

```
<div>
    @input(['type'=>'hidden','value'=>'Bar'])
</div>
```

Trying to use the Text and Hidden include does not work as I'm getting the:

`Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController not defined.` error, however everything is fine when using just the Input include. I've done all of the above with Components instead and ended up with the same outcome.

Does anyone know whether the above is possible and I'm just missing something? Or do I need to go about this differently?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172361/error-when-trying-to-view-page-following-error-action-facade-ignition-http-con

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I posted this too soon. My quotes weren't closing properly, and the error message appears to be generic and doesn't reflect the actual error.